# How to set output context for list options in dialogflow?

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

How do I give an output context to each item of a list ? 
I am having trouble with handling the list options because the output context is not there.
For example in this code :

```
const meditatetrackList = () => {
  const list = new List({
    title: 'Choose a track.',  
    items: {
           'healing water': {
       title: 'Healing Water',
       synonyms: ['healing water'],
       image: new Image({
         url: 'http://www.vstplanet.com/News/2016/Nature-sounds/Relaxing-nature-sounds.jpg',
         alt: 'healing water',
       }),

     },
     'elven forest': {
       title: 'Elven Forest',
       synonyms: ['elven' , 'forest' , 'elven forest'],
       image: new Image({
         url: 'https://scx2.b-cdn.net/gfx/news/2018/europeslostf.jpg',
         alt: 'elven forest',
       }),
     },
      'warm light' : {
        title : 'Warm Light',
        synonyms: ['warm','light','warm light'],
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://www.socwall.com/images/wallpapers/37753-2000x1300.jpg',
          alt: 'warm light',
        }),
      }
    }
  });
  return list;
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by output context. When someone clicks on a list, they will [send you a callback](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/responses#list).

Comment: The problem I faced was one intent not recognizing which intent to go to next. 
One intent had a list of categories and the other intent had a list of tracks for each category. I had two more intents for playing the tracks. One for playing say sleep tracks and one for meditation tracks. After the list of tracks intent , it wouldnt know which media playing intent to go to next and give an error. I have fixed it by only using a single media playing intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I am late here but I recently did this.

In this example code, I am returning a dropoff list of items

**Util.js**

```
getDropOffListCard: function(nearestDropOffResponse, agent) {
        let objItem = {};
        for (let index = 0; index < nearestDropOffResponse.length; index++) {
            const element = nearestDropOffResponse[index];
            let key = element.name.toUpperCase().replace(/ /g, "_");
            let each = {
                synonyms: [
                    'synonym 1',
                    'synonym 2',
                    'synonym 3',
                ],
                title: element.name,
                description: element.address + '\n' + element.distance + ' ' + element.unit,
                image: new Image({
                    url: url + 'info-icon.png',
                    alt: 'Image alternate text',
                })
            };
            objItem[key] = each;
        }
        agent.context.set({ // here set the context
            name: 'global_context',
            lifespan: 2,
            parameters: {
                dropLocationList: objItem
            }
        });
        return new List({
            title: 'Nearest drop off location',
            items: objItem
        });
    }
```

**app.js**

```
intentMap.set("Nearest Drop Off Intent - yes", function(agent){
        const conv = agent.conv();
        conv.ask('Here are nearest drop off location. Where you can drop or pickup your parcel.');
        conv.ask(trackingUtil.getDropOffListCard(nearestDropOffResponse, agent));
        agent.add(conv);
 });
```

Create another intent to handle this and add the event **Google Assistant Option** this event do the trick, it will send the selected option to your intent handler, where you can access the selected option as well as a list that we set in context.

```
intentMap.set("Nearest Drop Off Intent - yes - selected", function(agent){
   const option_intent = agent.context.get('actions_intent_option');
    const option_key = option_intent.parameters.OPTION;
    const global_context = agent.context.get('global_context');
    const selection = global_context.parameters.dropLocationList[option_key]
    agent.add(selection.title);
    agent.add(selection.description);
    agent.add(trackingUtil.dropOffDetailCard(selection))
});
```

[image]